# how to enable buttons by using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have disabled all the buttons at my jsf page by using JQuery.Unfortunately, after that
process I realized I need some buttons enabled at my screen.

Could you please look at below and help me how to enabled buttons by using jQuery?
I tried several jquery functions but did not succeed at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best Regards
Alper Kopuz

This is my JavaScript that I defined at the beginning of the page :

```
  <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var kaydetBtnEnabled = #{genelKrediView.kaydetButonEnabled(gercekKrediBasvuruDetayGirisView.mst.durumKodu)};
 if(!kaydetBtnEnabled) 
 {
     jQuery('input[type=text]').attr('readOnly',true);
     jQuery('button').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
     jQuery('.ui-selectonemenu').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
     jQuery('.ui-inputtextarea').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
     jQuery('button').attr('onclick','');
     jQuery('button').attr('type','button');
     }
    });
    </script>
```

And my button  :

```
   <p:commandButton action="#{gercekKrediBasvuruDetayGirisView.basvuruTamamIsle()}" 
                             update = "@form" 
                             id="basvuruTamam"
                             value="Basvuru Tamam"
                                oncomplete="setTimeout('genelKrediViewMstUpdateEt();',500);activeteTab('tablar:tab1')"
                             icon="#{msg['approvIcon']}"
                             rendered="#{genelKrediView.mst.durumKodu eq 'YENI'}"
            styleClass="basvuruTamamBtnClass"/>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .prop attribute;

$('#YourButtonId').prop('enabled', true);

Answer (score 0):

you have made all `text` inputs `readonly`.

To again enable it to edit, use

```
jQuery('input[type=text]').prop('readOnly',false);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5Nve/)